# Returning an empty list on Google App Engine behaves differently on the dev server and when deployed

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I've created an endpoint that returns a list of items. When the list is empty, I was expecting to see an empty list in the JSON, but the list field was instead omitted. That's not what happens on the dev server.

Ex:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "udinic", path = "udinic")
public List<UdinicResponse> getUdinics() {
    List<UdinicResponse> list = new ArrayList<>();

    UdinicResponse res = new UdinicResponse();
    res.bla = "sds";
    list.add(res);

    return list;
}

static class UdinicResponse {
    String bla;

    public String getBla() {
        return bla;
    }

    public void setBla(String bla) {
        this.bla = bla;
    }
}
```

When I run this on the dev server, that's the response I get:

```
{
items: [ ]
}
```

When it's on the deployed server, that's what I get:

```
{
kind: "udinicEndpoint#resourcesItem",
etag: ""3Ms41gaYW9qnDr8JAXr8FIDhu9jVetg""
}
```

Any ideas how can I get a consistent behavior? I prefer to get an empty list instead of omitting the field.

Comment: I am having this same issue using GCE in the Go runtime. It seems to work as desired in the dev environment. But when deployed on App Engine, my empty arrays get omitted. If the element is NULL or has >0 values then it's fine. Perhaps a bug report needs to be opened for GCE.

Comment: I am in the Go runtime as well and experiencing the same issue. I have opened an issue on the GAE issue tracker. Please feel free to comment on and star the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behavior is that empty lists will be omitted, as per the documentation [1]:

> Empty Lists that are returned will arrive as nulls on the client-side.
>   Remember to check for those.

So the actual issue is the development server is not consistent with production. As a workaround for consistency on the development server, you can add a check for an empty list and return null instead.

```
return list.isEmpty() ? null : list;
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/

Comment: What's the same for python?