# Returning an empty list for an attribute in cloud endpoint API removes the whole attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints for API creation. Returning an empty list to an attribute results the removal of whole attribute in the json response. How to overcome this problem?

Exact same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483121/returning-an-empty-list-on-google-app-engine-behaves-differently-on-the-dev-serv) but it's for different language.

```
class ContactMessage(messages.Message):
    user_key = messages.StringField(1)
    name = messages.StringField(2)

class ContactsListResponse(messages.Message):
    contacts = messages.MessageField(ContactMessage, 1, repeated=True)
```

In the API, if I use `return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[])`, the whole `contacts` attribute got removed.. I have tried the below but none works,

```
return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[None])
return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[''])
```

Think the contacts attribute should hold a list of `ContactMessage` objects. So I also tried,

```
return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[ContactMessage()])
```

But this also won't work.. Think modifying the return like

```
return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[ContactMessage(userkey='None')])
```

Should work but it requires some extra validation check in the client side..

Comment: {
 "contacts": [
  {
  }
 ]
}   **is this the way you want result in JSON if list is empty**

Comment: let me try ..............

Comment: @HardikSachdeva no it's not working...

Comment: it's was not the solution . I was just confirming the JSON result format you want.  Please try this                                                                                                        return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[ContactMessage(user_key= None,name = None)])

Comment: Think the above would work, currently I'm write it like `return ContactsListResponse(contacts=[ContactMessage(userkey='')])` . So there is no way to shorten this ...